# function to multiplying the values in a dictionary - Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary

I am trying to define a function that performs the function of an boolean logic OR gate. The function should ideally accept a dictionary as my data is in a dictionary format.

I have looked up different things but I am now stuck.

I have started with somethign like this:

```
d = {'26': [0.5], '22': [0.5], '12': [0.5]}
def OR_function(**parameters):
    pi *= (1 - parameters)
    return (1 - pi)
OR_function(**d)
```

(I know it's wrong)

Then after reading around all day I have managed to unpack the dictionary but I am still not able to perform the recursive in place product. I have had a look at functional programming operators but they accept only two parameters [https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html].

My function definition at the moment looks something like this:

```
import operator
def OR_function(**parameters):
print(operator.imul(list(*parameters)))
#pi = 0
#for i, j in parameters.items():
#    pi *= (1 - j[0])
#print(pi)
return 1 #- pi
```

and it raises the following error:
'TypeError: op_imul expected 2 arguments, got 3'

Can someone help me?
Alternative ways to approach this are welcome. Please do explain the code in the answer so I can learn something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood what you are trying to do there should be no need to unpack the dictionary. This worked for me:

```
d = {'26': [0.5], '22': [0.5], '12': [0.5]}

def OR_function(parameters):
  pi = 1

  print(parameters)
  print("=================")

  for key, value in parameters.items():
      print(pi)
      pi *= (1 - value[0])

  print("=================")
  print(pi)
  return (1 - pi)


OR_function(d)
```

Which yields this output (and it seems correct):

```
{'22': [0.5], '12': [0.5], '26': [0.5]}
=================
1
0.5
0.25
=================
0.125
```

If the values in the dictionary are lists with more than one element the changes needed are very small, you only need an extra for loop:

```
d = {'26': [0.5, 0.7], '22': [0.5, 0.9], '12': [0.5, 0.5]}

def OR_function(parameters):
  pi = 1

  print(parameters)
  print("=================")

  for key, value in parameters.items():
      for x in value:
          print(pi)
          pi *= (1 - x)

  print(pi)
  return (1 - pi)


OR_function(d)
```

From the commented code you posted:

```
#pi = 0
#for i, j in parameters.items():
#    pi *= (1 - j[0])
#print(pi)
```

It looks like your problem was that you were initialising the variable `pi` to 0, which will yield the value of 0 in a recursive multiplication.